# How can one identify and store variables and data from a formatted text file in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, file

I am trying to identify and then store data from a text file in Python. It's been some time since I last used Python so I might just be rusty on this. Essentially the text file has data of the form

```
<THING1> \ 
 var1         =  0        \#
   var2      = "0.0 100.0 0.0"          \#
var3     = "IDENTIFYING_WORD"      \#
var4      = 2                 \#
</THING1>

<THING2> \
 # something similar
</THING2>
```

I've been able to identify the section of the text file that I need and store it as a big long string. Assuming the file is called data.txt,

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    content  = f.read()
    t1start  = content.find('<THING1>')
    t1end = content.find('</THING1>')
    t1 = content[t1start:t1end]
    f.close
```

From here I'm not sure where to take it. I'm able to identify the newline breakpoints and am trying to use that, but I'm sure it's going to work. For example, I can say

```
i1 = t1.index('\n')
i2 = t1[i1+1:].index('\n')
line1 = t1[i1:i2]
```

but this is not exactly what I want.

Ideally, I would like the data to be stored in Python as

```
var1 = 0
var2 = [0, 100, 0]
var3 = "IDENTIFYING_WORD"
var4 = 2
```

where var1 and var 4 are ints, var2 is an array, and var3 is a string. Does anyone have thoughts on this? I've tried looking elsewhere on Stack, but I can't find anything. If this has been answered, kindly direct me in the right direction and I'll take this down.

Thanks!

Comment: My mistake. They are forward-slashes "</THING>".

Comment: Yes. They are all always of the form "<THING>(space)\"

Answer (score 2):

Usually when people start coding with python they'll be tempted to solve these typical parsing problems by using simple methods like string manipulation or regular expressions... Both methods are fine when it comes to solve simple problems but for more complex ones there are better choices.

For example, for this particular question, there is no real reason for not trying one of the many existing available [python parsing tools](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/python-parsers.html). To prove this point, let's see how you could solve this problem using [lark](https://github.com/lark-parser/lark) library.

After you've pip installed `lark-parser` try this snippet:

```
import sys
import textwrap
from lark import Lark

if __name__ == "__main__":
    content = textwrap.dedent(r"""

    <THING1> \
     var1         =  0        \#
       var2      = "0.0 100.0 0.0"          \#
    var3     = "IDENTIFYING_WORD"      \#
     # something similar
    var4      = 2                 \#
    </THING1>

    <THING2> \
     # something similar
     var1         =  0        \#
    </THING2>

    """)

    grammar = r"""
        ?start: block*
        block:  tag_start line* tag_end
        tag_start: "<" NAME ">" "\\"
        tag_end: "</" NAME ">"
        line: assignment
            | comment
        assignment: lhs "=" rhs "\#"
        comment: "#" NAME* NEWLINE
        lhs: NAME
        rhs: ESCAPED_STRING
            | NAME
            | NUMBER

        %import common.NEWLINE
        %import common.ESCAPED_STRING
        %import common.CNAME -> NAME
        %import common.NUMBER
        %import common.WS

        %ignore WS
    """

    parser = Lark(grammar)
    tree = parser.parse(content)

    for block in tree.find_data("block"):
        tag_name = list(block.find_data("tag_start"))[0].children[0]
        print(tag_name.center(80, '-'))
        for assignment in block.find_data("assignment"):
            var_name = assignment.children[0].children[0]
            value = assignment.children[1].children[0]
            print(var_name, "=>", value)
```

You should get something like this:

```
-------------------------------------THING1-------------------------------------
var1 => 0
var2 => "0.0 100.0 0.0"
var3 => "IDENTIFYING_WORD"
var4 => 2
-------------------------------------THING2-------------------------------------
var1 => 0
```

The above example doesn't intend to be a full example covering all nitty details but just a little example about how easy is to address these simple problems with a modern parsing library. I'll leave it as a simple exercise for you to adjust the code and play around with lark to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use regex like this:

```
import re

def get_value(y):
    if 'var1' in y or 'var3' in y or 'var4' in y:
        return_value = y.split('=')[1].strip()
        try:
            return int(return_value)
        except ValueError:
            return return_value
    elif 'var2' in y:
        return_value = y.split('=')[1].strip().split(" ")
        return [float(i.replace('"','')) for i in return_value]


string = """
<THING1> \ 
 var1         =  0        \#
   var2      = "0.0 100.0 0.0"          \#
var3     = "IDENTIFYING_WORD"      \#
var4      = 2                 \#
</THING1>

<THING2> \
 var1         =  5        \#
   var2      = "0.0 100.0 0.0"          \#
var3     = "IDENTIFYING_WORD"      \#
var4      = 7                 \#
</THING2>
"""



pat = re.compile(r'<THING\d>(.*?)</THING\d>')
x = re.findall(pat, string.replace('\n',''))
mainlist = [['var1','var2','var3','var4']]
for i in x:
    mylist = []
    for j in i.split(r'\#'):
        if j.strip() != '':
            mylist.append(get_value(j))
    mainlist.append(mylist)
print(mainlist)
```

Result:

```
[
    ['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4'], 
    [0, [0.0, 100.0, 0.0], '"IDENTIFYING_WORD"', 2], 
    [5, [0.0, 100.0, 0.0], '"IDENTIFYING_WORD"', 7]
]
```